# How to Convert String into Integer using Vuejs, vuex?

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js, vuejs2

I have a Little Problem with my application.
I am currently making a Basic stock Trader app (as an exercise). I am using Vuejs and Vuex. 
In my store.js file I am storing all the global variables but there is this problem with the `bmw_quantity` data.
It is mapped to a v-model (Input field) which you can see in the stocks.vue component. For some reasons the data is always a string. I don't know why and I also tried several things but I couldn't convert the things I type in the field into an actual integer and not a string.

Here is my code:

[image: image 1]

[image: image 2]

Comment: Always post your code as text (and format it as code), not screenshots! This is really important to find problems again.

Answer (score 15):

You can use the `.number` modifier: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html#number

```
<input v-model.number="bmw_quantity" type="number">
```

Comment: Thank you very very much. I am quite knew to this (6 months) and still not knowing sooo much Things.

You saved my evening. :)

Comment: It‘s alright, that‘s why I‘m telling you. :) Please mark as solved when it works.

Comment: Dear @JohnKohlmeier... Please spare a few seconds to mark correct answer! Developers like me will feel easy to find such solutions.